# How to replace IP address with another one?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg

How to replace IP address with another one ?

[image]

without adding a new lines

Comment: You could simply add an IAT hook for the socket function. That way you don't even need to modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to where the ip is hardcoded in binary (make sure to analize the code using AnaliseThis! plugin)

the ip probably is in some address on the pushes after the function (i think you are looking on the wrong place)

I just hope that Steamcl module dont means Steam Cloud (im pretty sure that is) you may get sued for reversing steam softwares

and by the way, next time make a more specified question, and don't act like a ironic guy on commentaries, no one is obligated to answer you.

see ya.